# Groovy GString fails to interpolate a variable when referenced by an interface

Tags: grails, groovy

##### Summary

I have a very odd situation where a GString is incorrectly interpolating a variable as `null` even though the variable has a non-null value set.  See the screenshot below.  However, it interpolates correctly if I reference the variable by its actual class rather than by the interface.

##### `PublicBinary` is an interface

```
interface PublicBinary {

    byte[] bytes
    String publicKey
    Person person
}
```

##### `AdditionalPhoto` is the concrete class that implements `PublicBinary`

```
class AdditionalPhoto implements PublicBinary, ToMap, DomainClass {

    byte[] bytes
    String publicKey
    String externalURL
    Person person
    AdditionalPhotoType additionalPhotoType
...
}
```

##### Interpolation fails when I type the variable as its interface, `PublicBinary`

[image]

##### But interpolation works properly when I type the variable as its actual class, `AdditionalPhoto`, rather than as its interface, `PublicBinary`.

[image]

Comment: "Groovy GString fails to interpolate a variable when referenced by an interface" - FYI... Your code doesn't appear to be using `GString` interpolation.  `photo.publicKey + ".jpg"` doesn't involve interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you are describing but the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation demonstrates an approach that works.

[lib/src/main/groovy/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/PublicBinary.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/blob/74da67a64c266b1e3d5332a66459c661ff6e13c4/lib/src/main/groovy/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/PublicBinary.groovy)

```
package tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation

interface PublicBinary {
    byte[] bytes
    String publicKey
    Person person
}
```

[lib/src/main/groovy/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/AdditionalPublicBinary.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/blob/74da67a64c266b1e3d5332a66459c661ff6e13c4/lib/src/main/groovy/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/AdditionalPublicBinary.groovy)

```
package tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation

class AdditionalPublicBinary implements PublicBinary {
    byte[] bytes
    String publicKey
    String externalURL
    Person person
}
```

[lib/src/main/groovy/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/Library.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/blob/74da67a64c266b1e3d5332a66459c661ff6e13c4/lib/src/main/groovy/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/Library.groovy)

```
package tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation

class Library {
    String processByInterface(PublicBinary obj) {
        return "Public Key Is [${obj.publicKey}]"
    }

    String processByConcreteType(AdditionalPublicBinary obj) {
        return "Public Key Is [${obj.publicKey}]"
    }
}
```

[lib/src/test/groovy/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/LibraryTest.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/blob/74da67a64c266b1e3d5332a66459c661ff6e13c4/lib/src/test/groovy/tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation/LibraryTest.groovy)

```
package tengritsandpapergstringinterpolation

import spock.lang.Specification

class LibraryTest extends Specification {
    def "someLibraryMethod returns true"() {
        setup:
        def lib = new Library()
        def binary = new AdditionalPublicBinary(publicKey: 'My Key Value')

        expect:
        lib.processByConcreteType(binary) == 'Public Key Is [My Key Value]'
        lib.processByInterface(binary) == 'Public Key Is [My Key Value]'
    }
}
```

One thing that is unusual is the way you have defined properties in both the interface and impl.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `interface`.  This is not the interface you are
intending, because it defines no getters (or maybe even setters) for
your property.  It defines un-initialized, public, final properties.

The following shows the problem:

```
interface I1 {
    String x
}

class X1 implements I1 {
}

println(new X1().x) // → null
```

If you decompile the "wrong" interface, you see what is going on:

```java
public interface I {
  public static final java.lang.String x;
}
```

While a "proper" interface will match your expectations:

```
interface I2 {
    String getX()
}

class X2 implements I2 {
    String x
}
```

Comment: "This is not a proper interface, because it defines no methods." - It isn't the case that an interface must define methods in order for it to be proper.  Many interfaces do not.